# Css overide for office fabri ui Pivot

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, spfx, react, office-ui-fabric-react

How can we do padding left in office fabric UI CSS for pivot component , Want to padding of Pivot component its working on develoepr tool added screenshot for same but not able to override through css in my solution

```
<Pivot linkFormat={PivotLinkFormat.tabs} linkSize={PivotLinkSize.large} >
    <PivotItem headerText="Current" itemIcon="Recent">
        <Label></Label>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding your custom class and CSS? Can you add any screenshot of how it is showing currently?

Comment: yes but not working

Comment: How exactly you want to show it? Can you add any screenshot or something? Where you want to add left padding? on `<Pivot>` or `<PivotItem>`?

Comment: without padding its not align with below component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the Pivot component inside a `div` element and add your custom style to it like:

```
<div className={styles.pivotWrapper}>
    <Pivot linkFormat={PivotLinkFormat.tabs} linkSize={PivotLinkSize.large} >
        <PivotItem headerText="Current" itemIcon="Recent">
            <Label></Label>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</div>

.pivotWrapper {
    /*Your custom CSS goes here*/
}
```